# How does Spring boot server convert json to request object

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-boot

Sorry I am completely new to Spring boot, but am trying to add new APIs onto the server someone else wrote:

```
  @RequestMapping(value = RequestMappingConstants.CREATE_POST, method = RequestMethod.POST)
  public @ResponseBody Map<String, Object> createPost(@RequestBody Map<String, String> inputMap, HttpServletRequest request) {
    LOG.info("Inside createPost");
    return DataUtil.ConvertToResponseMap(socialService.createPost(CreatePostRequest.fromMap(inputMap)));
  }
```

In this Controller method, I accept a map, but it gives me the following error:

org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: JSON parse error: Cannot deserialize instance of `java.lang.String` out of START_OBJECT token; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot deserialize instance of `java.lang.String` out of START_OBJECT token

This is because I have a nested BaseUser object in the request object.

Ideally I would like to have the method look like this, taking in a request object instead of a map:

```
  @RequestMapping(value = RequestMappingConstants.CREATE_POST, method = RequestMethod.POST)
  public @ResponseBody Map<String, Object> createPost(@RequestBody CreatePostRequest request) {
    LOG.info("Inside createPost");
    return DataUtil.ConvertToResponseMap(socialService.createPost(request));
}
```

But this also had problems with filling in the nested object BaseUser.
So I was wondering, which part of the server converts the raw json into a map or the raw json into a request object? 
I didn't find any code that does this. Or is it in the annotations? Do I need to write something for it to parse nested objects from json?

This is my request object:

```
public class CreatePostRequest extends BaseRequest
{
    public BaseUser user;
    public String imageUrl;
    public String text;
}
```

And the BaseUser object:

```
public class BaseUser {
    public int userId;
    public String firstName;
    public String lastName;
    public int hairType;
    public String location;
    public String profileImageUrl;

    public BaseUser(){}

    public BaseUser(int userId, String firstName, String lastName, int hairType, String location, String profileImageUrl)
    {
        this.userId = userId;
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.hairType = hairType;
        this.location = location;
        this.profileImageUrl = profileImageUrl;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please go through https://www.baeldung.com/spring-httpmessageconverter-rest & [MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/converter/json/MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter.html)

Comment: Thanks, I did. When my CreatePostRequest object comes into the controller, its own primitive properties, such as Strings, are successfully deserialized. However, the complex object, the BaseUser, is causing an error, and the base class properties (i.e. the properties from the BaseRequest) are all null. Are DTOs only supposed to  have primitive properties and no superclasses?

Comment: Please go through [this](https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-inheritance) and [this](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-docs/wiki/JacksonPolymorphicDeserialization)

Comment: Also the official documentation to understand [message conversion](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/integration.html#rest-message-conversion)

Comment: The problem turned out to be that I forgot to mark the base class properties public and also the base class was named differently on the Flutter client and the Java server. Now both the base class properties and the nested object are being filled in.